# Simple PIC18 USART Interrupt not working

Tags: pic, uart, interrupts

I'm trying to implement a link between and Arduino and a PIC18F25K22.  I can transmit from the PIC and read the data on the Arduino, but am having trouble going the other direction.  I think the problem is with my interrupt service routine, but could be anything, of course.  I'm using MPLAB X 1.60 with XC8 1.12.  From the compiler's user guide, i've found this example.

> An example of an interrupt function is shown here.
>
> ```
> int tick_count;
> void interrupt tc_int(void)
> {
> if (TMR0IE && TMR0IF) {
> TMR0IF=0;
> ++tick_count;
> return;
> }
> // process other interrupt sources here, if required
> }
> ```
>
> Code generated by the compiler will be placed at the interrupt vector
>   address which will  execute this function after any context switch
>   that is required.

my own code is modeled after that, basically exactly.  Main is only setup, then a while(1).

```
void usart_setup()
{
    TX1_PIN = OUTPUT;
    RX1_PIN = INPUT;
    TXSTA1 = 0; // page 277, 8bits tx, async mode, low baud
    TXSTAbits.TXEN1 = 1; //tx enabled
    RCSTA1 = 0; // page 278, 8bit rx,
    RCSTA1bits.SPEN1 = 1; //serial enable bit
    RCSTA1bits.CREN1 = 1; //continuous receive enable bit
    BAUDCON1 = 0; // page 279
    BAUDCON1bits.DTRXP1 = 0; //Non inverted polarity
    BAUDCON1bits.CKTXP = 0; //idle state is high?
    // page 280, set to 9600 baud (actual 9615)
    SPBRG1 = 12; // baud rate low byte
    SPBRGH1 = 0; // buad rate high bit
    rx_pos = 0;
}

void setup(void)
{
    OSCCON = 0b11100110; // setup internal oscillatior to 8MHz, TCY is 0.5 microsecond
    RCONbits.IPEN = 0; //no interrupt priority
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; // enable interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // enable peripheral interrupts
    PIE1bits.RC1IE = 1; // enable USART receive interrupt
}

void interrupt ISR()
{
    if (PIE1bits.RC1IE && PIR1bits.RCIF) // if the USART receive interrupt flag has been set
    {
        PIR1bits.RCIF = 0;
        usart_tx_byte(RCREG1);
        //dealt with interrupt
    }
}
```

For now, it should just echo anything received back, but instead does nothing.  I've double checked the connections, and I know transmit works, so I'm at a loss.

**Edit**

So talking to the duck and some more searching here seems to have solved it.  On power on and reset, ports are set to be analog.  I now disable this in my setup.  It was a problem between this and my RX1 pin.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint, does the ISR trigger?

Comment: I go it working, thanks.  I really wish I had a way of debugging in the circuit.

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: @TrentonHolmes if you have a solution which can be useful to other users as well, please add it as an answer. If it isn't useful, please remove this question.